# Trigonometric integral with the function- sin

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I need some help with this integral please:

$\displaystyle\int x\sin\frac{1}{x}dx$

Comment: I'm pretty sure this integral is not elementary...

Comment: According to [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral&a=*C.integral-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=x*sin(1%2Fx)&f=Integral.integrand_x*sin(1%2Fx)&a=*FVarOpt.1-_**-.***Integral.rangestart-.*Integral.rangeend--.**Integral.variable---.*--) this is not elementary, because it need the integral sine (the primitive of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$).

Answer (score 1):

$\int x\sin\dfrac{1}{x}dx$

$=\int x\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{-2n-1}}{(2n+1)!}dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{-2n}}{(2n+1)!}dx$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{1-2n}}{(2n+1)!(1-2n)}+C$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)!(2n-1)x^{2n-1}}+C$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $~t=\dfrac1x$ , then, after a bit of [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts), use the [trigonometric integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral) $\text{Si}(x)$.